# In py.test, how can I narrow the scope of an xfail mark?

Tags: pytest

I would like to narrow the scope of the pytest xfail mark.  As I currently use it, it marks the entire test function, and any failure in the function is cool.

I would like to narrow that down to a smaller scope, perhaps with a context manager similar to "with pytest.raises (module.Error)".  For example:

```
@pytest.mark.xfail
def test_12345():
    first_step()
    second_step()
    third_step()
```

This test will xfail if I assert in any of the three methods I call.  I would like instead for the test to xfail only if it asserts in second_step(), and not elsewhere.  Something like this:

```
def test_12345():
    first_step()
    with pytest.something.xfail:
        second_step()
    third_step()
```

Is this possible with py.test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a context manager yourself that does it, like this:

```
import pytest

class XFailContext:
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, type, val, traceback):
        if type is not None:
            pytest.xfail(str(val))
xfail = XFailContext()

def step1():
    pass

def step2():
    0/0

def step3():
    pass

def test_hello():
    step1()
    with xfail:
        step2()
    step3()
```

Of course you can also modify the contextmanager to look for specific exceptions.
The only caveat is that you cannot cause an "xpass" outcome, i.e. a special result that the (part of the) test unexpectedly passed.

Comment: That works exactly as you described.  It's not perfect because of the xpass hole, but it's much better than what I've been dealing with.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that when step2() fails (as expected), step3() is not executed.